# ASP.NET Web Api: Delegate after Request

Tags: sockets, stream, asp.net-web-api

I have a problem with streams and the web api.

I return the stream which is consumed by the web api. Currently, i put the socket into a pool after getting the stream. but this cause some errors.

Now, I must putthe socket into the pool AFTER the request ended. (The stream was consumed and is now closed).

Is there a delegate for this or some other best practises?

Example code:

```
public HttpResponseMessage Get(int fileId)
{
HttpResponseMessage response = null;
response = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);

Stream s = GetFile(id);

response.Content = new StreamContent(fileStream);

}

GetFile(int id)
{
FSClient fs = GetFSClient();
Stream s = fs.GetFileStream(id);
AddFSToPool(fs);

return s;
}
```

GetFile uses a self-programmed FileServer-Client.
It has an option to reuse FileServer-Connections. This connections will be stored in a pool. (In the pool are only unused FileServer-connections). If the next request calls GetFSClient() it gets an connected one from the pool (and removes it from the pool).

But if another requests comes in and uses a FileServer-Connection which is in the pool (because unused), there is still the problem, that the Stream is possibly in use.

Now I want to do the "put the FSClint into the pool" after the request ended and the stream is fully consumed.

Is there an entry point for that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Stream` is seen as a volatile/temporary resource - no wonder it implements `IDisposable`.

Also `Stream` is **not thread-safe** since it has a `Position` which means if it is read up to the end, it should be reset back to start and *if two Threads reading the stream they will most likely read **different** chunks*.

As such, I would not even attempt to solve this problem. Re-using streams on a web site (inherently multi-user / multi-threaded) not recommended.

---

### UPDATE

As I said, still think that the best option is to re-think the solution but if you need to register something that runs after request finishes, use `RegisterForDispose` on request:

```
public HttpResponseMessage Get(HttpRequestMessage req, int fileId)
{
   ....
   req.RegisterForDispose(myStream);
}
```

Comment: I do not want to reuse the stream. I want to reuse the connection to another computer. I hold the sockets in a dictionary using the "lock" keyword. The problem was that the socket is again in the pool (because unused) but the stream is still not closed and in use. I now handle this better. but it would be interesting if there is an point to do something before the response gets out.

Comment: Thank you for your effort. This is interesting for disposing ressources. But I do not have this problem anymore. I meant "do something". Like add an event-handler and my own method will be executed before the response goes out. But thank you for the "RegisterForDispose". Maybe this is usefull for another scenario.